# What are the building blocks of a set?

Tags: c, data-structures, set

I have this assignment to implement a data structure set in C and we've been given a struct and then it's out job to allocate memory for it, fill in values, etc. I'm a tad bit confused about what I've been given here. What is a set's size and capacity?

From what I understand, capacity is how many elements are in a set and size is how many elements can be fit in a set. So I've allocated memory for struct set and made size = 0 since there aren't any elements in it initially, then allocated memory for array of size int. But this doesn't feel right.

If anyone can help explain to me the difference between a set's capacity and size as well as what I should initialize, that would be great. Below the struct is my attempt at allocating memory which may help explain my thought process.

```
struct set {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    char *array;
};

struct set *initialize(){
    struct set *new_set = malloc(sizeof(struct set));
    
    ptr->array = malloc(sizeof(char));
    ptr->size = 0;
    ptr->capacity = 0;
    
    return new_set;
}
```

Comment: "*capacity is how many elements are in a set and size is how many elements can be fit in a set.*". I would say it is the opposite. `capacity` is the allocated size. `size` is how many actual elements the set currently contains. So should allocate some `MAX_CAPACITY` for `array` and then set `capacity` to `MAX_CAPACITY` and `size` to 0.

Comment: What if I don't know how many elements I'm going to add? should I just allocate memory for capacity instead?

Comment: You are doing `malloc(sizeof(int))` for `array` but you have `char *array;`!? What do you want `array` to be? A _single_ string or a _list_ of strings?

Comment: @CraigEstey oh, my bad... fixed it. It's supposed to be an array of characters. Just more used to allocating memory for ints

Comment: you should allocate memory for `capacity` chars.  If that ends up being too many, it's "just" wasted memory at worst.  If it ends up being too little, you can either fail to add elements if the array is full , or use `realloc()` to allocate more memory (which might incur a copy of existing memory)

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer `struct set *new_set = malloc(sizeof *new_set);` and `ptr->capacity = 1; ptr->array = malloc(ptr->capacity * sizeof *ptr->array); ` - It makes mistakes less likely.